# App only support iOS 8.. not iPhone 6 & iPhone 6 plus

Tags: iphone, ios8

I am developing app that only support iOS 8.. not compatible for iPhone 6 & iPhone 6 plus. so i have a query related that i have to add @3x size icons in Image Assets? having confusion on it..

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You want to support iOS8 but you don't want to support iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus? If that is the case no you need to support iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus because iOS8 is capable of running on those devices.

Comment: If you want to support iOS8 only then you need to support iPhone 6 and 6+.

Comment: I tried to find in [Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) where it says "you must support all devices capable of running the versions of iOS your app supports", however I couldn't.  Can someone provide a link to where Apple state this?

Comment: @Droppy There is no link. If you support an iOS version for iPhone and/or iPad you must support all the iPhone/iPad versions that iOS is capable of running on. So because iOS8 is capable of running on devices going back to iPhone 4S (Not sure about iPhone 4) you must support all devices from iPhone 4S onwards. This is well known and isn't anything new

Comment: @Popeye Well if Apple don't state that explicitly, they are wasting time and effort.  Massive failing on their part and it's no wonder the OP doesn't know this.

Comment: @Droppy this is well known and common sense. Except for between iPhone and iPad you don't develop an app that should only run on a specific iPhone you make it for the iOS that is why you can drop support for earlier iOSs. Here is a list of devices that support iOS 8 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices This isn't exactly rocket science to understand. Apple don't explicitly say a lot but it is still common knowledge and common sense.

Comment: @Popeye The issue isn't about how complex this concept is, it's about Apple failing to document this condition.  It doesn't matter if it's *well known*, it needs to be stated somewhere a developer can find it easily.  Apple have failed to do that.

Comment: @Droppy No they have documented it perfectly well by not allowing you to do it without private APIs and as such you would get rejected under **2.5** of the Apple review process and/or could even get rejected under **2.22** as you are arbitrarily restrict users by device so they're ruling that this could be rejected under. Minus the fact that there is no actual way of doing it is the best way of documenting it. Just because Apple don't say that an iPhone can't be used as a blow torch doesn't mean it can.

Comment: Neither 2.5 nor 2.22 seem to apply in this case.

Comment: @Popeye yes i want to support only ios8.. not iPhone 6 & 6+.. iPhone 5, 5s these devices can update to iOS 8..

Comment: @Droppy The only way to stop supporting iPhone 6 and/or iPhone 6+ would be to use private APIs which would get your app rejected under **2.5** so yes that is perfectly valid reason for rejection. Or the only other way would be to check in code what the device is and do nothing after loading so because of that the app would get rejected under **2.22** because you are restricting what device the application will function on correctly. So both are perfectly valid reasons for rejection if you don't like that apple don't have this written down then go complain but it is common common sense.

Comment: @iphoneDev sorry dude but this isn't possible you need to support all versions of the iPhone device that iOS 8 runs on there is no way (except for private APIs which aren't allowed to be used) to restrict based on device.

Comment: Well the OPs app would obviously run on iPhone 6 and 6+, but it would not run optimally.  I think that's pretty obvious.  So neither clauses apply.

Comment: @Droppy that isn't what was being said. I said the only way to restrict it so it doesn't run on iPhone 6 and 6+ would be to use private API or check the device on load up and do nothing after the lunch image. As such both would ways would get rejected from the review process. Simple fact is if you support iOS 8 you have to support iPhone 6 and 6+ there is no getting around it.

Comment: @Popeye You have misunderstood the question.  The OP asked if he had to supply 3x images in order to (properly) support iPhone 6 and 6+; he never said "I want to stop my app running on iPhone 6 and 6+".

Comment: @popeye Actually 5 days ago i have submitted app with Xcode 6.0.1 and it only support only iOS 8 not support iPhone 6 & iPhone 6+ and now its on app store. but in that app i have set 3x size app icons. but i have a confusion that its necessary to not?

Comment: @Droppy is there any doc or something that tell that you your app is rejected if that not support for iPhone 6 & 6 plus?

Comment: Cause if you don't add default image sizes 750 * 1334, 1242 * 2208.. your app is perfectly running on both devices (6 , 6+) just issue is with display images...

Comment: @Droppy note I added that their question was confusing from the get go however my comments are towards your very first comment. You challenged it with this "you must support all devices capable of running the versions of iOS your app supports" when `Frogmeister` added his comment.

Comment: @iphoneDev This is what we are discussing.  It seems "no" however the feeling is that it's obvious and common sense and you should already know this.  However my issue is that Apple should explicitly state this.

Comment: @Droppy they don't have to explicitly state anything if they don't actually make it possible to do. Like I say just because Apple don't **explicitly** the iPhone can't be used as a blow torch doesn't mean it can. Use a little common sense.

Comment: @Popeye I don't think there is a reason to be offensive.  My issue is with Apple and not with you.  They do explicitly state plenty of things in their guide, so this would not be out of place.  I think you are right, however I would like to see if Apple have documented it, that is all, so that developers know what to expect.  There are many reason a developer might be unable to supply 3x images and it would instructive to know what Apple would do with the app.

Comment: @Droppy the reason they haven't explicitly is because it doesn't actually need saying, there is a lot Apple don't say somethings yeah they maybe should to make it clear but a lot is just using a little bit of common sense (By blow torch analogy). If you really want to know what they would reject your apps under just submit an app for review that doesn't contain the required images. Normally with Apple if they don't provide a way of actually doing it then that is their way of documenting it.

Comment: You can just throw an exception if you detect the device is one of the iPhone models. So the user will know your app won't support iPhone 6.

Comment: @StudentT Oh no.  That is not what the OP or his users want.

Comment: @StudentT also I believe that you are restricting the users by device then so that would be rejected under **2.22**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I asked the question on the [Apple Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/250440?tstart=0) and here is an answer I got in return:

> That is a given by Apple's design. Apps already in the wild perform
>   whatever OS magic to support those devices. You are not required to
>   explicitly support them (but they should still run in emulation mode).
>
> Also you may note every second game on the App Store states things
>   like "will not run on anything before iPad 2" and that kind of thing
>   and that's merely a designer/technical choice Apple seem happy with
>   regardless of many customers not reading these things or understanding
>   them and buying anyway.

Now this is someone's *opinion* (much like the answers and comments here), however the answer does seem to make sense.

However the only real way to know if Apple will reject the app is to submit it (it's a hit and miss process).

Comment: so this says that no need to add 3x size icons in app. and as i stated before that.. if i haven't do any changes in app then its perfectly run on both devices.

Comment: @iphoneDev Yeah, but please take note of the last sentence in my answer.  It's hit and miss and you might just get the wrong reviewer :)

Comment: oh thats why my app is now status "Ready to sale". :) thanks for this information.